# KMM iOS HttpClient NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition type error issue

Tags: ios, kotlin, kmm

I am still new to KMM and need help on httpClient to ignore ssl certificate. I had made the request able to ignore ssl certificate by adding the following code to HTTPClient Android Engine:

```
HTTPClient(Android){
    engine{
        sslManager = {
                httpsURLConnection ->
            httpsURLConnection.hostnameVerifier = HostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true }
                httpsURLConnection.sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
        }
    }
}
```

and on iOS Engine:

```
HTTPClient(Ios){
    engine{
        handleChallenge { session, task, challenge, completionHandler ->
                completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, null)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have an issue on iOS side. NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential despite inheriting from NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition is a type of Kotlin.Long, but the completion handler’s first param only take NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition which is a type of platform.darwin.NSInteger.

At first, i thought to just convert NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential to Int or platform.darwin.NSInteger. It didn’t triggered any error at android studio, but once i build it from xcode the following error pops up:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but
> NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition /* = Long */ was expected

I think this is a bug because the xcode expect NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition to be a long value, while kmm accept type of platform.darwin.NSInteger.

Comment: Have you tried building your code? It may be IDE bug, in this case the build should work fine. In any case, I suggest you [report it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue).

Comment: I can't build it on Xcode. The build failed with the type mismatch error above. I will try reporting it.

Comment: Try converting it to `Long`, as the error suggests

Comment: I tried that too even though NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential  supposed to be Long too, but the following error appear on the Android Studio side:

"Type mismatch.
Required: NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition /* = Int */
Found: Long".

The completionHandler doesn't accept Long, only NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition which is a type of platform.darwin.NSInteger.

Comment: This is the IDE bug I was talking about, if it builds fine, I suggest leaving it like this

Comment: You're right! It builds just fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The build is failing in latest version of Kotlin 1.9.10 and Ktor 2.3.4 with the exact error. Any suggestions?